# Remove unused views display id

Tags: views, blocks

I was making changes to the views display machine names or(ID) and while i create
some display it popped up this message (Display id should be unique) which was by
this name "power_sector_1_1" and it was old id and its deleted, how can i clear the old deleted displays which not used any more to use any ID 
I want for the new
display [pages - blocks]

Comment: Have you tried clearing caches?

Comment: why exactly would you care about specific IDs?